# How to send parameter on function calling in "jQuery Ui Draggable Helper"?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jQuery UI plugin for drag'n drop my object, But I have a problem.
My html Source is like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="firstDiv">some thing is here</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to draggable the above div, using helper. My code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#firsstDiv").draggable({helper:anImage});
 });
 function anImage() {
  return '<img src="~/myImage.png" alt="" />';
 }
</script>
```

Ok, this code is work as well, but I want to set image address, But when i change my function to have a parameter, that doesnt work, O_o

My new code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#firsstDiv").draggable({helper:anImage($(this).text())});
 });
 function anImage(address) {
  return '<img src="'+address+'" alt="" />';
 }
</script>
```

but not working.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You want your function to take in the address as a parameter?  Could you post the code that you've tried?  What doesn't work?

Comment: **<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#firsstDiv").draggable({helper:anImage(address)});
 });
 function anImage(address) {
  return '<img src="'+address+'" alt="" />';
 }
</script>
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - you can't pass a parameter into your helper function.  I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

The way around this would be to create a setup function and then call your `anImage` function from there:

```
$(function(){
    $("#firsstDiv").draggable({
        helper: setup
   });
});

// function to setup draggable DOM elements
function setup() {
    anImage("~/myImage.png");
    // ... do other setup things here too
}

function anImage(imageAddress) {
    return '<img src="'+imageAddress+'" alt="" />';
}
```

Unless of course you are trying to call `anImage` with a different image address for each draggable element, in which case the above will not work.  But you shouldn't be using the helper function to do this anyway as I'm pretty sure it's just meant to contain code to setup all of the draggable elements you are creating.

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: ok, nice cheat ;). But i have more than one div, and this address is not same. like this= 'helper: anImage(**$(this).text()**)'

Comment: that's what I meant in my final comment - you shouldn't be using the setup method to setup the individual requirements of each draggable div, it should be used to setup all the generic properties of each div.  You would want to do something different for setting up each individual div.